# Doubt in Dominated Convergence theorem

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

From Browder's Mathematical Analysis

[image]

On applying Fatou's Lemma to sequence ${(g \pm f_n)}$ we get $\int \liminf (g \pm f_n) \leq \liminf \int(g \pm f_n)$.

My question is how they got as $\int (g \pm f) \leq \liminf \int (g \pm f_n)$.

Is $\int \liminf (g \pm f_n)=\int g \pm f$,How?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Limits, when they exist, are equal to limit inferiors/superiors:$$g \pm f=g\pm\lim f_n=\lim(g\pm f_n)=\liminf g\pm f_n$$

Comment: But why the $\lim(g \pm f_n)$ will exist?

Comment: By assumption, $f_n\to f$, so $g\pm f_n\to g\pm f$..

Comment: what is the guarantee that $g$ will take finite values? If it takes infinity as value,we can say about the convergence or the existence of limit?

Comment: $g$ being summable means that $g$ is integrable on every compact set, so in particular in every interval $[-n,n]$, $n$ a positive integer. So the set $\left\{x\in [-n,n]:g(x)=\pm\infty\right\}$ has measure $0$. The set on which $g=\pm\infty$ is the (countable) union of those sets, so it also has measure $0$. Thus $|g|<\infty$ almost everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall (or try to prove) some basic facts about numerical sequences:

- for any numeric convergent  sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$, $\lim_n(a_n+b_n)=\lim_na_n+\lim_nb_n$
- if $c=\liminf_nc_n:=\sup_n\inf_{m\geq n}c_m$, then there is a subsequence $n_k$ along which $\lim_k c_{n_k} = c$.
- For any nonempty numeric subset $-\sup A=\inf(-A)$, where $-A=\{-a:\in A\}$. From this, it follows that $-\limsup_m d_n=\liminf_n(-d_n)$
- If $a_n$ converges, then $\liminf_n(a_n+b_n)=\lim_na_n +\liminf_nb_n$ and $\limsup_n(a_n+b_n)=\lim_na_n+\limsup_n b_n$.
- In the case that concerns you, for each $x$, there is a subsequence $n^{(x)}_n$ such that $\lim_k \big(-f_{n^{(k)}_k}(x)\big)=\liminf_n\big(-f_n(x)\big)$.